# Apply CSS to nested HTML code

Tags: html, css, class, stylesheet

So, I have this code in "index.html" file:

```
<div id="Vsebina">
<div class="Slika"></div>
<div id="Prvi" class="Vrh">
<h2>Odstavek 1</h2>
<p><span class="Lorem">Lorem ipsum</span> dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis .</p>
</div>
```

I have a stylesheet linked to this html document and I am wondering how I can change the text inside class "Lorem" and "p". I have tried typing in my CSS file:

```
#Vsebina #Prvi .Vrh .Lorem{
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Nothing happens. If anyone can help me I would be very grateful, thanks.

Comment: Where is #Drugi element?

Comment: I'm sorry, it is supposed to say "Prvi"

Comment: Ok, I can see your error and I update my answers below :)

Comment: Just do: `.Lorem { text-transform: uppercase; }`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`#Prvi` does not have any children which has `Vrh` class and `text-transformation` is invalid property so do these:

Change `text-transformation: uppercase;` to `text-transform: uppercase;`

Change `#Vsebina #Prvi.Vrh .Lorem` to `#Vsebina #Prvi.Vrh .Lorem`

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6oxv7vf9/3/)

```css
#Vsebina #Prvi.Vrh .Lorem  {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="Vsebina">
  <div class="Slika"></div>
  <div id="Prvi" class="Vrh">

    <h2>Odstavek 1</h2>

    <p><span class="Lorem">Lorem ipsum</span> dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis .</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Updated**

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6oxv7vf9/4/)

```css
#Vsebina #Prvi.Vrh p  {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="Vsebina">
  <div class="Slika"></div>
  <div id="Prvi" class="Vrh">

    <h2>Odstavek 1</h2>

    <p><span class="Lorem">Lorem ipsum</span> dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis .</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the nearest I can get, but this changes my h2 also, I dont want that in this case. Definitely put me on the right path,

Comment: This is it. Thank you so much!

Comment: I did not. I upvoted you... but im under 15 votes, so they dont even count

Comment: which is weird, because your answer is the one that helped me:p thank you

Comment: @DomenLisjak Please, accept it as answer, If it is your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.Lorem {
     text-transform: uppercase;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="Vsebina">
    <div class="Slika"></div>
    <div id="Prvi" class="Vrh">
      <h2>Odstavek 1</h2>
      <p><span class="Lorem">Lorem ipsum</span> dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis .</p>
    </div>
```

In this code above, you miss close div with id Vsebina. You should do like this:

```
<div id="Vsebina">
    <div class="Slika"></div>
    <div id="Prvi" class="Vrh">
      <h2>Odstavek 1</h2>
      <p><span class="Lorem">Lorem ipsum</span> dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis .</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And your DOM path must like this:

```
#Vsebina #Prvi .Lorem
```

or

```
#Vsebina .Vrh .Lorem
```

Comment: I copied sloppily, but this only affects the text: "Lorem ipsum" in Lorem class, I need it to affect the whole <p>

Comment: Yes, if you want effect this CSS to all p element in page, you just use .Lorem :)

Comment: but .Lorem ends, but the text continues, I need it to affect the continuing text also.

Comment: Ok, use can do that: p {......}. Your all p element in page will be affect this css